# SQL values disappear when using max dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

First time posting here and have a query that I hope someone maybe able to help with, i have tried to search for the answer but with no joy.

When i use the below SQL to find a value (in this case eb.annualvalue) it returns multiple values because no end dates have been entered into the eb table and there are too many employees without end dates for me to close down.

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        eb.empid, eb.bencode, eb.currencycode AS [currencycode], eb.notes AS [notes], eb.annualvalue
    FROM
        employeebenefit AS [eb]
    WHERE
             eb.bencode IN ('US 401K Plan')
        AND (eb.enddate IS NULL OR eb.enddate >= '20180101')
)
    AS eb26
        ON eb26.empid = e.empid
```

However, when i use MAX startdate (code  below) it returns the correct number or rows however, the eb.annualvalue figure disappears.

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        eb.empid, eb.bencode, eb.currencycode AS [currencycode], eb.notes AS [notes], eb.annualvalue
    FROM
        employeebenefit AS [eb]
    WHERE
             eb.bencode IN ('US 401K Plan')
        AND (eb.enddate IS NULL OR eb.enddate >= '20180101')
        AND (eb.startdate = (SELECT MAX(eb.startdate) FROM employeebenefit AS [eb]))
)
    AS eb26
        ON eb26.empid = e.empid
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Dan.

Comment: The reason that it doesn't work is that the `(SELECT MAX(eb.startdate) FROM employeebenefit AS [eb])` returns the max date ***of the whole table***.  Please could you explain what you actually ***want*** that to do?  Preferably with example data.  *(The answer below is a good way to achieve what I **think** you want to do, but until you explain it we're really just guessing.)*

Comment: As  mentioned below. I'm trying to create a pivot view of benefits paid to an employee. Unfortunateky there is no end date against 4 entries and so i need a way to select both the most up to date record and it's corresponding value. Thanks.

Comment: To paraphrase: `employeebenefit` has multiple rows per `empid`, you want just "the *newest* `'US 401K Plan'`" row for each `empid`.  By newest you mean the one with the highest `startdate`?  *(Where does the filter on the `enddate` fit in with this?)*

Comment: Yes that is correct the most recent start date. Enddate has to be used because some employees do have end dates though having said that i suppose if I'm selecting the most recent start date the end date is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code bellow , if I undestood your question

```
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        eb.empid, eb.bencode, eb.currencycode AS [currencycode], eb.notes AS [notes], eb.annualvalue
    FROM
        employeebenefit AS [eb]
    WHERE
            eb.empid = e.empid 
        AND eb.bencode IN ('US 401K Plan')
        AND (eb.enddate IS NULL OR eb.enddate >= '20180101')
    ORDER BY
        eb.startdate DESC
)
    AS eb26
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately i couldn't get it to run on my system. I did try playing around with the code and changing a few things but to no avail. I think what I'm trying to do is create a pivot view of all benefits however some people will have more than one benefit and so i have created new inner views (sorry not sure if that's the right terminology) for each benefit name, so i do need to reference the eb26 (there are upto 30 left joins). Some benefits have no end date even though they have been superseded by a new benefit. so somehow i need to select the most recent record

Comment: it's hard to understand the situation without the code, and table structures, but if you want to get the recent row meeting some conditions , than the usage of `apply` is one of the good solutions. so you can cope with it.

Comment: @Danboi - What do you mean "couldn't get it to run on my system"?  Did you get errors?  Supply them if you did.  Did you get unexpected results?  Show them if you did.  This answer *should* do the same as my answer, but probably more efficiently.

Comment: Hi Mat, apologies for the delayed reply. Unfortunately I've had this flu that's been going around and have been ill since Thursday. Thanks for the above code unfortunately it doesnt run on the system and the only error code i get is 'The Sql text is invalid for this query'. Anyway. Thanks. I think i'll need to do some further reading on this as i beyond my SQL capabilities at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a `greatest-n-per-group` problem, you just want one row per employee, from a table with many rows per employee.  I'm not 100% clear on how you want to select that one row, but I can give an example.

Ideally, you would use `ROW_NUMBER()` but that only came in to effect from SQL Server 2008 onward.

The two commons alternative are:
 - Join on your data twice.  Once to find the "highest date" per user, again to find the whole row.
 - Use a correlated sub-query to work out an individual's best row *(still really joining twice)*

Simple-self-join:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        empid,
        MAX(startdate)    AS max_startdate
    FROM
        employeebenefit
    WHERE
             bencode IN ('US 401K Plan')
        AND (enddate IS NULL OR enddate >= '20180101')
    GROUP BY
        empid
)
    latest_employeebenefit
        ON latest_employeebenefit.empid = e.empid
LEFT JOIN
    employeebenefit
        ON   employeebenefit.empid     = latest_employeebenefit.empid
        AND  employeebenefit.startdate = latest_employeebenefit.max_startdate
        AND  employeebenefit.bencode IN ('US 401K Plan')
        AND (employeebenefit.enddate IS NULL OR employeebenefit.enddate >= '20180101')
```

This has the "feature" that if two such records both match the max_startdate *(a tie)* then both will come through.  Often that is impossible, often it's desirable, it depends on your data and your needs.

Correlated-sub-query for join:

```
LEFT JOIN
    employeebenefit
         ON  employeebenefit.id =
             (
                 SELECT TOP(1) lookup.id
                   FROM employeebenefit  AS lookup
                  WHERE lookup.empid = e.empid           -- the correlated bit
                    AND lookup.bencode IN ('US 401K Plan')
                    AND (lookup.enddate IS NULL OR lookup.enddate >= '20180101')
               ORDER BY lookup.startdate DESC
             )
```

This is slightly different in that it always returns just one row.  If there can be a tie when only sorting by `startdate` it's generally best to add another column to the `ORDER BY`, even if it's just an `id` column, to ensure the results are deterministic.